# SQL query to return records

Tags: sql

I have two queries in my sp

the first query returns values like

```
ID   Name Department 

1     Sang    IT

2    Div       IT

3     SS      EEE
```

and I have second query which returns value like

```
1  Sang  IT

2  Div    IT

4   Pav   EEE
```

Now when combining the result i need to get

```
ID   Name Department

1     Sang    IT

2    Div       IT

3     SS      EEE

4   Pav   EEE
```

How can I get this one? I tried using union  but it dint work for me, it returns duplicate values.

Here is my complete query, I am not sure how to remove duplicates?

```
SELECT 
Riskdetail.RiskID,Riskdetail.[RiskTitle],a.RiskRegisterID,DivisionDesc,BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupDesc,a.RiskRegisterDesc,RiskGroup.RiskGroupDesc, 
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID) as [Assigned RiskOwner],dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID) as [Assigned RiskOwner2],
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID) as [Assigned ActionOwner],dbo.GetUserNameFromLoginName(LoginName) as [Assigned User],
[Assigned UserRole] = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct '','' + Role.RoleDesc 
           FROM UserRole b 
           inner join Role on Role.RoleID=b.RoleID
           WHERE b.RiskRegisterID = a.RiskRegisterID 
           and b.UserID in ('+ @UserID +') 
          FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, '''')
FROM RiskRegister a
inner join RiskDetail on RiskDetail.RiskRegisterID=a.RiskRegisterID
INNER JOIN  RiskGroup ON a.RiskGroupID = RiskGroup.RiskGroupID
INNER JOIN Division ON RiskGroup.DivisionID=Division.DivisionID
INNER JOIN BusinessGroup ON Division.BusinessGroupID=BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupID
INNER JOIN [UserRole] on [UserRole].RiskRegisterID=a.RiskRegisterID
inner join [User] on [User].UserID=UserRole.UserID
where ([User].UserID in ('+ @UserID +') and RiskDetail.RiskStatusID=100 and a.Deleted=0 and a.Inactive=0)
GROUP BY 
a.RiskRegisterID,Riskdetail.RiskID,Riskdetail.[RiskTitle],
DivisionDesc,BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupDesc,a.RiskRegisterDesc,RiskGroup.RiskGroupDesc,
dbo.GetUserNameFromLoginName(LoginName),
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID),dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID),
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID)
union 
select RiskDetail.RiskID,Riskdetail.RiskTitle,Riskregister.RiskRegisterID,Division.DivisionDesc,BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupDesc,RiskRegister.RiskRegisterDesc,RiskGroup.RiskGroupDesc,
    dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID) as [Assigned RiskOwner] ,
    dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID) as [Assigned RiskOwner2],
    dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID) as [Assigned ActionOwner],NULL as [Assigned User], 
    Null as [Assigned UserRole]
    from RiskDetail 
    join RiskRegister on  Riskdetail.RiskRegisterID=RiskRegister.RiskRegisterID
    join RiskGroup ON RiskRegister.RiskGroupID = RiskGroup.RiskGroupID
    JOIN Division ON RiskGroup.DivisionID=Division.DivisionID  
    JOIN BusinessGroup ON Division.BusinessGroupID=BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupID 
    where RiskDetail.RiskStatusID=100 and RiskRegister.Deleted=0 and RiskRegister.Inactive=0 and (RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID in ('+ @UserID +') or RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID in ('+ @UserID +') or RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID in ('+ @UserID +'))'
```

Comment: Show us the SQL sentences that you are using.

Comment: Did you use union or union all?

Comment: UNION will work, but only if the user is showing the exact columns he is using

Comment: Do these tables have other columns you are not showing?

Comment: Can you post your actual query that you tried?

Answer (score 3):

use union

```
select id, name, departement
from ... 
UNION
select id, name, departement
from ...
```

to remove duplicates try

```
select distinct id, name, departement
from ( 
    select id, name, departement
    from ... 
    UNION
    select id, name, departement
    from ...)
```

or

```
select * from ( 
    select id, name, departement
    from ... 
    UNION
    select id, name, departement
    from ...)
group by id, name, departement
```

Comment: UNION will remove duplicates by itself so no need to use GROUP BY

Comment: yes, i also thought so, but @Sangeetha Vimal said, that union didn't remove the duplicates... that's why I added these solutions too

Comment: If is it so then OP is retrieving more columns which are not specified in question

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Union, but you could always use a left join...

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.id,b.id) AS 'ID'
       ISNULL(a.Name,b.Name) AS 'Name'
       ISNULL(a.Department,b.Department) AS 'Department'
FROM TABLEA AS A LEFT JOIN
     TABLEB AS B ON a.ID = b.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like:

```
select id, name, departement
from Query1
union 
(select id, name, departement
from Query2
except 
select id, name, departement
from Query1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your SELECTS would be:

```
SELECT a.a, a.b FROM whatever1 a WHERE a.a=foo
SELECT b.c, b.d FROM WHATEVER2 b WHERE b.c=bar
```

I would try joining both and then concatenating the (NULL-free) Values. I guess something like this:

```
SELECT f.fc, CONCAT(nvl(f.fd, ""), nvl(g.gb, "")) FROM (SELECT b.c fc, b.d fd FROM WHATEVER2 b WHERE b.c=bar) f, (SELECT a.a ga, a.b gb FROM whatever1 a WHERE a.a=foo) g WHERE f.fc = g.gb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is my complete query, i am not sure how to remove duplicates?

SELECT 
Riskdetail.RiskID,Riskdetail.[RiskTitle],a.RiskRegisterID,DivisionDesc,BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupDesc,a.RiskRegisterDesc,RiskGroup.RiskGroupDesc, 
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID) as [Assigned RiskOwner],dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID) as [Assigned RiskOwner2],
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID) as [Assigned ActionOwner],dbo.GetUserNameFromLoginName(LoginName) as [Assigned User],
[Assigned UserRole] = 
    STUFF((SELECT distinct '','' + Role.RoleDesc 
           FROM UserRole b 
           inner join Role on Role.RoleID=b.RoleID
           WHERE b.RiskRegisterID = a.RiskRegisterID 
           and b.UserID in ('+ @UserID +') 
          FOR XML PATH('''')), 1, 1, '''')
FROM RiskRegister a
inner join RiskDetail on RiskDetail.RiskRegisterID=a.RiskRegisterID
INNER JOIN  RiskGroup ON a.RiskGroupID = RiskGroup.RiskGroupID
INNER JOIN Division ON RiskGroup.DivisionID=Division.DivisionID
INNER JOIN BusinessGroup ON Division.BusinessGroupID=BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupID
INNER JOIN [UserRole] on [UserRole].RiskRegisterID=a.RiskRegisterID
inner join [User] on [User].UserID=UserRole.UserID
where ([User].UserID in ('+ @UserID +') and RiskDetail.RiskStatusID=100 and a.Deleted=0 and a.Inactive=0)
GROUP BY 
a.RiskRegisterID,Riskdetail.RiskID,Riskdetail.[RiskTitle],
DivisionDesc,BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupDesc,a.RiskRegisterDesc,RiskGroup.RiskGroupDesc,
dbo.GetUserNameFromLoginName(LoginName),
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID),dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID),
dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID)
union 
select RiskDetail.RiskID,Riskdetail.RiskTitle,Riskregister.RiskRegisterID,Division.DivisionDesc,BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupDesc,RiskRegister.RiskRegisterDesc,RiskGroup.RiskGroupDesc,
    dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID) as [Assigned RiskOwner] ,
    dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID) as [Assigned RiskOwner2],
    dbo.GetUserName(RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID) as [Assigned ActionOwner],NULL as [Assigned User], 
    Null as [Assigned UserRole]
    from RiskDetail 
    join RiskRegister on  Riskdetail.RiskRegisterID=RiskRegister.RiskRegisterID
    join RiskGroup ON RiskRegister.RiskGroupID = RiskGroup.RiskGroupID
    JOIN Division ON RiskGroup.DivisionID=Division.DivisionID  
    JOIN BusinessGroup ON Division.BusinessGroupID=BusinessGroup.BusinessGroupID 
    where RiskDetail.RiskStatusID=100 and RiskRegister.Deleted=0 and RiskRegister.Inactive=0 and (RiskDetail.ActionOwnerID in ('+ @UserID +') or RiskDetail.RiskOwnerID in ('+ @UserID +') or RiskDetail.RiskOwner2ID in ('+ @UserID +'))'
```